# 1D to 2D array - python

Tags: python

I would like to change the data stored in 1D into 2D:
I mean:

from

```
x|y|a
1|1|a(1,1)
2|1|a(2,1)
3|1|a(3,1)
1|2|a(1,2)
...
```

into:

```
x\y|1     |2     |3
1  |a(1,1)|a(1,2)|a(1,3
2  |a(2,1)|a(2,2)|a(2,3)...
3  |a(3,1)|a(3,2)|a(3,3)...
    ...
```

I did it by 2 loops:

```
(rows - array of x,y,a)
for n in range(len(rows)):
            for k in range(x_len):
                    for l in range(y_len):
                            if ((a[2, n] == x[0, k]) and (a[3, n] == y[0, l])):
                                    c[k, l] = a[0, n]
```

but it takes ages, so my question is if there is a smart and quick
solution for that in Python.

**So to clarify what I want to do:**

I know the return() function, the point is that it's randomly in array **a**.

So:

> ```
> a = np.empty([4, len(rows)]
> ```

I read the data into array **a** from the database which has **4 columns (1,2,x,y)** and **'len(rows)' rows**.

I am interested in '1' column - this one I want to put to the new modified array.

> ```
> x = np.zeros([1, x_len], float)
>
> y = np.zeros([1, y_len], float)
> ```

**x** is a vector of sorted **column(x)** from the array **a**, but without duplicitas with a length **x_len**

(I read it by the sql query: select distinct ... )

**y** is a vector of sorted **column(y)** from the array **a** (without duplicitas) with a length **y_len**

Then I am making the array:

> ```
> c = np.zeros([x_len, y_len], float)
> ```

and put by 3 loops (sorry for the mistake before) the data from array a:
>

> ```
>  for n in range(len(rows)):
>      for k in range(x_len):
>         for l in range(y_len):
>           if ((a[2, n] == x[0, k]) and (a[3, n] == y[0, l])):
>               c[k, l] = a[0, n]
> ```

Example:

Array **a**

> ```
>    array([[1, 3, 6, 5, 6], 
>           [1, 2, 5, 5, 6], 
>           [1, 4, 7, 1, 2],   ## x
>           [2, 5, 3, 3, 4]])  ## y
> ```

Vectors: **x** and **y**

> ```
>  [[1,2,4,7]]   ## x with x_len=4
>
>  [[2,3,4,5]]   ## y with y_len=4
> ```

Array **c**

> ```
>    array([[1, 5, 0, 0], 
>           [0, 0, 0, 0],  
>           [0, 0, 0, 3],  
>           [0, 6, 0, 0]])
> ```

the last array **c** looks like this (the first a[0] is written into):

> ```
>  x\y 2|3|4|5
>  -----------
>  1   1|5|0|0
>  2   0|0|0|0
>  4   0|0|0|3
>  7   0|6|0|0
> ```

I hope I didn't make mistake how it's written into the array **c**.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: I know you probably spent a lot of time formatting your question, but all the <br /> make it hard to help with the formatting.

Comment: got rid of the <br /> and made it look easier. Next time use the `code` tags so its easier to see your code :)

Comment: There are three loops here, not two. And what's the value of `len(rows)`? You seem to be looping through `x` and `y` values, testing each pair against a single `a` row. There's almost certainly a better way of doing this, but I can't tell what `x`, `y`, and `a` are; your indexing makes it look as though they are more complex data structures. Give us a simple example -- say, a 9 row example, written out in correct Python syntax, so that we can simply copy and paste the code. Then give the 3x3 grid that should result.

Comment: I edited my question, as I couldn't post the new answer, thanks

Comment: Does anyone know how to solve that? :(

Answer (score 7):

You could use [numpy:](http://scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List_With_Doc)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(9)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
>>> a.reshape(3,3)
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
#or:
>>> a.reshape(3,3).transpose()
array([[0, 3, 6],
       [1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8]])
```

Comment: Does the reshape() function mind the order of data in the array?
Cause it's random in my array a. And I can't crearly see that reshape() solves my problem...